# Why won't Opera let me use the Ubuntu font?

Tags: fonts, opera, ubuntu-font-family

This is driving me crazy. I'm using monochrome rendering for fonts and this causes a few problems in my browser so I wanted to make Ubuntu the standard sans-serif font. I changed it in the preferences and it initially works okay but after a while it reverts to the default. If I go into the font section in the menu, it still lists Ubuntu and if I click OK the pages will correct themselves. Does anyone know I can stop this behaviour?

I'm using Opera 11 on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: You should file a bug report at https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ .

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've done as suggested. I also asked on the Opera forums, but wanted to ask Ubuntu as well since the community support is so good.

Comment: Did you change the font in the section "Preference -> Web pages" or in the section "Preferences -> Advanced -> Font". To get the font work correctly I had to chage everything subsection of the latter one. Also did you try to use dragonfly (rigth click then "inspect element") on a webpage that doesn't display correctly to see where opera look for the font (i.e. in user css, or the webpage css). Finally, are you in author mode or in user mode (in page-> style), the behaviour change totally depending on which mode you use.

Comment: I had changed it in the advanced section, but I've also now changed it in the web pages section (though I know it won't make a difference for sites that are requesting sans-serif). I've not heard of this Dragonfly so will look into that. I'm always just in user mode.

Comment: Have you tried this? : In page -> style -> edit modes, check the box "my font and colour" and maybe uncheck the box "font and colour of the page" in the user mode column. This will probably override any font entries on the webpage you visit however. (The path to the thing maybe wrong because I'm translating from my french version of Opera).

Comment: Sorry, just realised the default is author mode, so that's what I've been using. I've played about with the settings for author and user modes but, as you mentioned, I don't want to override fonts on all websites.

Comment: **Roddie:** Do you have links or bug numbers for where you've raised this with Opera?  As well as linking to those (so that other people can follow along with updates!), how was your experience, have you any replies or updates you'd like to share?

Comment: The bug ID is DSK-324216. I got no response on the Opera forums and it hasn't been fixed in the latest release.

Comment: @Roddie Can you make an answer out of your efforts so the information people need isn't buried in the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an Ubuntu issue but rather an Opera bug and apparently it's been present since version 10.60 of the browser. It has been raised as such with the Opera team (the ID is DSK-324216) but as there has been no movement in nearly a year since reporting it, I'm not too hopeful of it ever being fixed.

I discovered a workaround which involves creating a .css file in `~/.opera/styles/user` and populating it with:

```
pre, code {
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}
```

You can then select this file in Preferences > Advanced > Content > Style Options... > My style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems than even in v12.00 Next, this bug is not fixed in Opera. The only thing we can do is: wait...

For this reasons, I love Launchpad.net and open source development. It’s always nice to follow progress of your bugs.